# Java >> operator find if characters are unique

Tags: java, string, character, operator-keyword

I am not really sure how this code works:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChar2(String str) {
    int checker = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i) );
        System.out.println(val);
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)
            return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

In particular I do not understand particular >> operator and the role of checker

Comment: Where you have used `>>` operation in your code ?

Comment: [Take a look at this reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this method is only designed to work for lower-case letters.  The `checker` variable is a 32-bit bitmap initialized to all `0`s.  The code `1 << val` takes a 1 and shifts it into the position of `val`, which represents a letter of the alphabet (a=0, b=1, c=2, etc.).  `if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)` returns `false` because any value other than 0 would indicate that a letter had been repeated.  The last line in the loop, `checker |= (1 << val);` sets the bit at position `val` before the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

> > and | are bitwise shift and binary or. I suggest you do some reading of binary and bitwise operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

a |= b is just a shorthand of a = a | b similar like a += b  to a = a + b

Comment: Where do you mention the bitwise shift?